# Dragging BufferedImage in JPanel

Tags: java, swing

I have JPanel inside JFrame and there are more than one BufferedImages in the JPanel like this.
[image]

Now my question is how can i move the BufferedImages inside the JPanel? More specifically How to add MouseEventhandler to the Buffered Images?. Though I can drag JPanel from the code below but can't figure out how to drag Buffered Images inside JPanel. Thanks for the help.

I have three classes like this

MainWindow.Java

```
 public class MainWindow extends JFrame {  
       public static void main(String[] args) {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
                            window.frame.setVisible(true);
                        } catch (Exception e) {

                        }
                    }
                });
            }

   public MainWindow() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            ....  // Other code of JFrame

            JPanel panel_3 = new JPanel();
            .... // other code of JPanel

            frame.getContentPane().add(panel_3);
            panel_3.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

            Drawing drawingObj = new Drawing();
                panel_3.removeAll();
                panel_3.add(drawingObj );

                drawingObj .revalidate();
                drawingObj .repaint();

            BasicDragging drag= new BasicDragging();
            panel_3.addMouseListener(drag);
            panel_3.addMouseMotionListener(drag);
        }    
}
```

Drawing.java

```
public class Drawing extends JPanel {
private BufferedImage Image1 ;
private BufferedImage Image2;
private BufferedImage Image3;
 public Drawing() {

   try {                
       Image1 = ImageIO.read(new File("path of file"));
       Image2 = ImageIO.read(new File("path of file"));
       Image3 = ImageIO.read(new File("path of file"));
        }
   catch (IOException ex) {
                // handle exception...
           }

@Override
     protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

         g.drawImage(Image1 , 150, 10, null);
         g.drawImage(Image2 , 150, 70,null);
      // Other code of drawing images

      }

    }
}
```

BasicDragging.java

```
public class BasicDragging extends MouseInputAdapter{
        Point location;
        MouseEvent pressed;

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me)
        {
            pressed = me;
        }

        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me)
        {
            Component component = me.getComponent();
            location = component.getLocation(location);
            int x = location.x - pressed.getX() + me.getX();
            int y = location.y - pressed.getY() + me.getY();
            component.setLocation(x, y);
         }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first suggestion would be a simple one...

As you can see you draw these images by coordinates, x and y.
You could add the MouseListener to JPanel. That's where the magic already happens and it would be rather confusing if you create more objects.

Now you only have to check if the mouse hover above a image and is pressed.
You only need to calculate the size and if the point is inside the image. 
If it is inside the image moves in the direction of the mouse.
And you shouldn't reset the position rather move it along.
That's how it is done. 
Just set the x and y for the images when the are clicked and pressed on.

I'd create an object DragImage which contains the core BufferedImage + coordinates that represent the x and y and it's size. Additionally i'd add a function that calculates public boolean isHovering(int x, int y).
It should work out. And the x and y coordinates are used in your draw function.

I hope you understand what i was trying to say

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using images and then writing code to determine which image has "been clicked" you can just use a `JLabel` with an `ImageIcon` to display the image. Then you can add your `MouseListener` to the `JLabel` and drag the label around the panel.

Using this approach the basic code for dragging components would be:

```
public class DragListener extends MouseInputAdapter
{
    Point location;
    MouseEvent pressed;

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me)
    {
        pressed = me;
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me)
    {
        Component component = me.getComponent();
        location = component.getLocation(location);
        int x = location.x - pressed.getX() + me.getX();
        int y = location.y - pressed.getY() + me.getY();
        component.setLocation(x, y);
     }
}
```

The code to use this class would be:

```
DragListener drag = new DragListener();
component.addMouseListener( drag );
component.addMouseMotionListener( drag );
```

You can also check out the [Component Mover](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/14/moving-windows/) which adds some more advanced dragging features.

You will need to use a null layout on the panel and set the size/location of the label. So you may want to use the [Drag Layout](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2011/10/23/drag-layout/) which simplifies this process for you.